# SQL Profiler shows the query before IEnumerable list is read

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ienumerable

I know that the execution of query with IEnumerable is deferred until an item(s) in IEnumerable is read.

When I pause the following code in the **second** line, I can see that the query is executed in the database through SQL Profiler. I thought the query should be executed in the database when the **third** line is executed:

```
1 IEnumerable<Item> items = dbContext.Items;
2 var a = 0;
3 gridview.DataSource= items.ToList();
4 gridview.DataBind();
```

Can anyone explain why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 3):

Casting a `DbSet` to `IEnumerable` does not execute a query. So, either the *dbContext.Items* method is overriden to executes a query and is not a simple property like:

```
public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Or, the demonstrated code is not the real code you are having issues with, and you are running the application in the *Release* configuration, that enables optimization. If the `a` variable is never used it will be optimized away, and you will actually break on the next statement. Which in turn can execute a query (if, for instance, it is a foreach statement).

In this case, switch to the *Debug* configuration, and make sure that "Optimize code" is unchecked on the build tab of the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Search for

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

this may be the cause.

Comment: Can you try to explain why this is causing an issue!

Answer (score 1):

As Roman has mentioned, assigning to IEnumerable does not fire query.

It is your debugger which is evaluating IEnumerable in Debug window either in Local or Watch, which is causing query to be fired. In most cases, Debug window asks you to explicitly show enumerables but seems somewhere you are reading your IEnumerable.

Check if you have any other code that may be using ToList.